# Arithmetic operations with fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to query the result of a subtraction between two fields?

E.g. There are two fields: "start", "end". I would like documents with `end - start > 10`.

Can this be done directly or the only way to do is to create a new field while loading the documents with this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script filter in your query might be the way to go.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [script filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) using the scripting syntax explained in the [scripting documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting).

For your specific issue, you might do something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['end'].value - doc['start'].value > 10"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where you can replace the `match_all` query with your own.

As it's probably clear from the code above, you can access [specific fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields) in your document with the sintax `doc['field']` and apply specific functions to their values. In this case, `.value` (without parenthesis) returns the value of the field itself.

Comment: Is it possible to do a multiplication? `"script": "doc['end'].value = doc['start'].value * 10"`