# How to perform the arthimatic operation on data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I need to have average of cpuload on specific nodetype. For example if I give nodetype as `tpt` it should give the average of `cpuload` of `nodetype`'s of all `tpt` available. I tried different methods but vain...

My data in elasticsearch is below:

```
{
   "took" : 5,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
     "total" : 5,
     "successful" : 5,
     "failed" : 0
   },
   "hits" : {
     "total" : 4,
     "max_score" : 1.0,
     "hits" : [
       {
         "_index" : "kpi",
         "_type" : "kpi",
         "_id" : "\u0003",
         "_score" : 1.0,
         "_source" : {
           "kpi" : {
             "CpuAverageLoad" : 13,
             "NodeId" : "kishan",
             "NodeType" : "Tpt",
             "State" : "online",
             "Static_limit" : 0
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "_index" : "kpi",
         "_type" : "kpi",
         "_id" : "\u0005",
         "_score" : 1.0,
         "_source" : {
           "kpi" : {
             "CpuAverageLoad" : 15,
             "NodeId" : "kishan1",
             "NodeType" : "tpt",
             "State" : "online",
             "Static_limit" : 0
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "_index" : "kpi",
         "_type" : "kpi",
         "_id" : "\u0004",
         "_score" : 1.0,
         "_source" : {
           "kpi" : {
             "MaxLbCapacity" : "700000",
             "NodeId" : "kishan2",
             "NodeType" : "bang",
             "OnlineCSCF" : [
               "001",
               "002"
             ],
             "State" : "Online",
             "TdbGroup" : 1,
             "TdGroup" : 0
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "_index" : "kpi",
         "_type" : "kpi",
         "_id" : "\u0002",
         "_score" : 1.0,
         "_source" : {
           "kpi" : {
             "MaxLbCapacity" : "700000",
             "NodeId" : "kishan3",
             "NodeType" : "bang",
             "OnlineCSCF" : [
               "001",
               "002"
             ],
             "State" : "Online",
             "TdLGroup" : 1,
             "TGroup" : 0
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

And my query is

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source" : "kpi[CpuAverageLoad].value > params.param1",
                        "lang"   : "painless",
                        "params" : {
                            "param1" : 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

but is falling as it is unable to find the exact source.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23908643/1531971

Comment: here it is nested mapping and hence the point

Comment: No, because you have not made your point. There is _nothing_ about "nested mapping" in your question. See [ask]. Show your research and ask a specific question.

Comment: i have used the below query to fetch
`
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source" : "kpi[CpuAverageLoad].value > params.param1",
                        "lang"   : "painless",
                        "params" : {
                            "param1" : 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
'

Comment: it is failling with 
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
i understand that my way greping source is not proper. Because i have map i.e kpi at beginning of data. So

Comment: Details about the question should be in the question itself, because comments can be deleted. [edit] the question and include relevant details.

Comment: Yes, it is updated.

Comment: i changed my query to 
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "script" : {
          "lang":   "expression",
                            "source" : "doc['kpi.CpuAverageLoad'].value * 5",
                              } } } } } }'

but still the same

Comment: Details about the question should be in the question itself, because comments can be deleted. edit the question and include relevant details.